# Move only files from list

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to create a list from one directory, alter the names to match another naming convention, and use that list to reference files in a different directory to be moved into yet another directory. I've gotten this far but shutil.move() is moving the entire directory instead of searching the list for matching file names.

I'm unsure how exactly to proceed, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#Goal is to create list from the reference folder, 
#change names in list to match naming convention in the source folder,
#and move only those files to the destination folder. 

import os 
import shutil

r = input("Reference Folder")
s = input("Source Folder")
d = input("Destination folder")
os.chdir(r)

if not os.path.exists(d):
    os.mkdir(d)
#creating filelist from reference folder
filelist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown = False):
    for file in files:
        filelist.append(file)

#changing filelist to match source folder's naming convention. 

os.chdir(s)

filelist = [f.replace('filling_mask', 'tex') for f in filelist]

print("Moving these")

print(filelist)

for t in filelist:
    shutil.move(s, d)
```

Comment: You variable names are not very descriptive (and you should change them), but shouldn't it be `t` you're trying to move, not `s`?

Comment: isn't it `shutil.move(t, d)` in the last line?

Answer (score 2):

Ok here is the tip for you, instead of:

```
for t in filelist:
    shutil.move(s, d)
```

Do this:

```
for t in filelist:
    print('From: {}\nTo: {}'.format(s,d))
    break
    #shutil.move(s,d)
```

Now the trick here is to make sure that the file location  exist and the destination folder too. By using print statement instead of actually moving stuff you can debug this endlessly.

A hint: `filelist.append(file)` only append the filename. You need to include the path too. One way is to use os.path.join (`os.path.join(root, file)`). Now when moving that file to a destionation folder you need to strip away the root and change it with destination.